# Alter the table by adding constraint and using index in postgresql getting an error syntax error at or near "("IDX_emp_PK

Tags: postgresql, indexing, alter

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_emp_PK ON
    EMP(ID);

ALTER TABLE EMP ADD
    CONSTRAINT PK_emp PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    USING INDEX IDX_emp_PK;
```

Comment: second one USING INDEX IDX_emp_PK;

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your script:

First: you can't use a non-unique index for a primary key constraint, so you need

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_emp_pk ON emp(id);
```

When you add a primary or unique constraint based on an index, you can't specify columns (as they are already defined in the index):

```
ALTER TABLE emp ADD
    CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY 
    USING INDEX idx_emp_pk;
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE SoRecord (
    id                bigint  ,
    name          varchar(32) NOT NULL,
);

Comment: I didn't created cloumn  id as primary key.so how it will be unique index

Comment: That script **does** create the missing primary key. However you don't need to create the index first, you could simply use `alter table emp add constraint pk_emp primary key (id)`

Comment: as you suggested I change the script but getting an Notice;

Comment: NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD CONSTRAINT USING INDEX will rename index "idx_emp_pk" to "pk_emp"

Comment: can we achieve this without changing the index name?